# java.nio.BufferOverflowException even though my buffer size is big

Tags: java, exception, buffer, nio, buffer-overflow

```
CharBuffer outBuffer = CharBuffer.allocate(BUFFERSIZE) //BUFFERSIZE is 100000                            
System.out.println(outBuffer.capacity()); //Prints 100000 (huge buffer)
outBuffer.put(new char[] {'a','m','a'});  //I try to input a few characters
```

And I get `Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException` when executing the code

I've spent good few hours on this issue.
It even happens when I try to insert a single character `outBuffer.put('a')`.

Why is this happening

Comment: I suggest adding these lines:  `System.out.println("position=" + outBuffer.position()); System.out.println("limit=" + outBuffer.limit());` The position must be less than the limit, or a BufferOverflowException occurs.

Comment: Thanks I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown does not result in that error. It is also missing a semicolon so it doesn't even compile.
Please show the actual code that is failing.
You may want to print outBuffer.remaining() before you insert.

Comment: This is correct, but it should be a comment, not an answer, as it does not answer the question.